# Highlight the matching content of a pair of braces in emacs

Tags: emacs

I had it once, and I cannot figure out how to turn it on again. In `c++-mode` (maybe in other modes as well), when I placed the cursor either right before an opening brace or right after it, apart from highlighting the braces themselves, emacs would also highlight the text which the pair surounds. How this feature called? How can I have it again?

Thnx!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
(show-paren-mode t)
(setq show-paren-style 'expression)
```

Emacs [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Matching.html#Matching) on `show-paren-mode`, however it does not mention `show-paren-style`. [This emacs-fu blog post](http://emacs-fu.blogspot.com/2009/01/balancing-your-parentheses.html) does.

Answer (score 3):

Are you thinking about hl-sexp mode.? I only use it for elisp mode. Never coded cpp.

[image]

Comment: This is very nice!! How ever not what I was looking for. I want something which highlight the region bounded between two matching braces only when the cursor is visiting either of the braces. Thanks anyway. I'll try what you linked to - it looks nice.

Comment: It was a long time but how do you enable such block highlighting?

Answer (score 3):

The package 'mic-paren' does this, along with telling you where the matching paren is if it's not visible.  Check it out [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MicParen).

This is my preferred setup:

```
(setq paren-dont-touch-blink t)
(require 'mic-paren)
(paren-activate)
(setq paren-match-face 'highlight)
(setq paren-sexp-mode t))
```

Which does highlight the text between parens.